# How to cancel Auto-renewable subscription bought in Testflight?

Tags: ios, testflight, in-app-subscription

I've read several topics on cancelling subscriptions in sandbox environment, but it seems to me that it could not be applied to TestFlight.

I can cancel sandbox subscriptions through Settings > App Store > Sandbox account.

But since TestFlight does not use sandbox account I cannot cancel a sub from there. Also, TF purchase does not appear in the list of regular subscriptions (Settings > Profile > Media & Purchases).

So my question is: is there any way to manually cancel auto-renewable subscription bought in TestFlight build of the app?

Comment: did you find any solution? I am also facing the same problem of how to cancel auto-renewable subscription bought from TestFlight app?

Comment: Not really. Seems to me like it's only possible when using sandbox purchase instead of TestFlight.

Comment: I have same problem.